# Use Cauchy-Riemann equations to prove that if the range of f(z) lies on the parabola $y=x^2$, f(z) is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $f(z)$ would be constant if the Cauchy-Riemann equations were both equal to zero. I'm not sure what it means by the range lies on the parabola. can anyone help me set this up to be solved?

Comment: If we denote the real resp. imaginary parts of $f$ by $u$ resp. $v$, the condition is $v = u^2$. Now differentiate.

Comment: If $z=x+iy$ then what is $z^2?$ What is the real part? Call that $u$ What is the imaginary part? Call that $v$ Now give it a try with those CR equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parabola in $\mathbb{C}$ is the set $P=\{a+bi:b=a^2\}$, so called because when $\mathbb{C}$ is drawn as a plane, this set corresponds to the graph of the equation $y=x^2$.

If $f(\mathbb{Z})\subset P$, then it follows that $(\Re f(z))^2=\Im f(z)$. Take a derivative and you'll find $f'(z)=0$.